# Docker - Name is already in use by container

Tags: docker, docker-run

Running the `docker` registry with below command always throws an error:

```
dev:tmp me$ docker run \
     -d --name registry-v1 \
     -e SETTINGS_FLAVOR=local \
     -e STORAGE_PATH=/registry \
     -e SEARCH_BACKEND=sqlalchemy \
     -e LOGLEVEL=DEBUG \
     -p 5000:5000 \
     registry:0.9.1
Error response from daemon: Conflict. The name "registry-v1" is already in use by container f9e5798a82e0. You have to delete (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
```

**How can I prevent this error ?**

Answer (score 683):

I got confused by this also. There are two commands relevant here:

```sh
docker run  # Run a command in a **new** container
```

```sh
docker start  # Start one or more stopped containers
```

Comment: So it is also important to use `docker ps -a` to see all containers in this case.

Comment: yes, `docker start -a container-name` is the command you can use to start a container that has been created with `docker run`. Note the `-a` flag which is shorthand for `--attach`. This way the container is started in the foreground, just like when you use `docker run` (which runs a container in the foreground by default).

Comment: does `start` command rerun the container with the same settings (ports, dependencies, etc)?

Comment: @Suncatcher Yes.

Comment: this is another case of unfortunate naming.  I try to exec a container which errors, tells me it's not running.  Intuitively I run the container to resolve the issue but that creates a container ?  jeez

Comment: this may be useful information, still it's not a proper answer to the question.

Answer (score 379):

That means you have already started a container in the past with the parameter

```
docker run --name registry-v1 ...
```

You need to delete that first before you can re-create a container with the same name with

```
docker rm registry-v1
```

When that container is sill running you need to stop it first before you can delete it with

```
docker stop registry-v1
```

Or simply choose a different name for the new container.

To get a list of existing containers and their names simply invoke

```
docker ps -a
```

Comment: But why are the ones that are stopped for? Or whats good if they are still there if they are stopped?

Comment: So you can run them later without recreating them

Comment: So you are basically saying "so that you can RUN the image once (i.e. produce the container then run the command in it), then START the container as many times as you wish". But why would we need to RUN something just once? Without even persisting the possible changes that "something" made to the container (remember, docker container state changes are lost unless committed).

Comment: If you know the name of your container you can remove it using this shortcut `docker rm $(docker ps -aq --filter name=myContainerName)`

Comment: I had one stopped because I suspended my machine while it was running.  I had started it with `--rm` but in this case, it was stopped (and with my limited skills, at least, there doesn't seem to be a way to resume it interactively).

Comment: @JujharSingh Why not only `docker rm myContainerName`?

Answer (score 222):

Here what i did, it works fine.

## step 1:(it lists docker container with its name)

```
docker ps -a
```

## step 2:

```
docker rm name_of_the_docker_container
```

Comment: This was helpful to me, the "docker ps" unintuitively needs to -a flag to return anything.

Comment: docker ps returns only running containers and needs -a for listing even the stopped ones.

Answer (score 109):

When you are building a new image you often want to run a new container each time and with the same name. I found the easiest way was to start the container with the **--rm** option:

```
--rm        Automatically remove the container when it exits
```

e.g.

```
docker run --name my-micro-service --rm <image>
```

Sadly it's used almost randomly in the examples from the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)

Edit: Read Lepe's comment below.

Comment: image or container?

Comment: Containers are run from built images. Roughly similar to class definition (image) and class instance (container).

Comment: First you say container, then image. That's unclear. Moreover, if a container for that image is already running, it will remain running after using `--rm`. It doesn't restart.

Comment: Just a note: `--rm` only works if you have created the container using `--rm` flag. This means, if you created the container without the `--rm` flag, you will have to remove it manually before you can take the advantage of the `rm` flag.

Comment: Sadly `--rm` doesn't work with `--restart always`.

Comment: Does `--restart always` work with `--name`? Logically if you are always restarting the container then it makes little sense to try and delete it when it exits.

Answer (score 96):

Just to explain what others are saying (it took me some time to understand) is that, simply put, when you see this error, it means you already have a container and what you have to do is run it. While intuitively `docker run` is supposed to run it, it doesn't. The command `docker run` is used to only **START** a container for the very first time. To run an existing container what you need is `docker start $container-name`. So much for asking developers to create meaningful/intuitive commands.

Comment: docker run = create docker container + start docker container

Answer (score 39):

You have 2 options to fix this...

1. Remove previous container using that name, with the command `docker rm $(docker ps -aq --filter name=myContainerName)`

   OR
2. Rename current container to a different name i.e change this portion  `--name registry-v1` to something like  `--name myAnotherContainerName`

You are getting this error because that container name ( i.e `registry-v1`) was used by another container in the past...even though that container may have exited i.e (currently not in use).

Answer (score 24):

**Cause**

A container with the same name is still existing.

**Solution**

To reuse the same container name, delete the existing container by:

```
docker rm <container name>
```

**Explanation**

Containers can exist in following states, during which the container name can't be used for another container:

- `created`
- `restarting`
- `running`
- `paused`
- `exited`
- `dead`

You can see containers in `running` state by using :

```
docker ps
```

To show containers in all states and find out if a container name is taken, use:

```
docker ps -a
```

Comment: If one wishes to re-use the container, then --rm is not the appropriate switch.
A simple "docker start {container name}" is sufficient.

Answer (score 20):

Here is how I solved this on ubuntu 18:

1. `$ sudo docker ps -a`
2. copy the container ID

For each container do:

3. `$ sudo docker stop container_ID`
4. `$ sudo docker rm container_ID`

Answer (score 19):

removing all the exited containers

```
docker rm $(docker ps -a -f status=exited -q)
```

Answer (score 14):

I was running into this issue that when I run `docker rm` (which usually works) I would get:

> Error: No such image

The easiest solution to this is removing all stopped containers by running:

```
docker container prune
```

Answer (score 13):

**The Problem**: you trying to create new container while in background container with same name is running and this situation causes conflicts.

**The error** would be like:

> Cannot create continer for service X :Conflict. The name X is already in use by container *abc123xyz*. You have to remove ot delete (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.

**Solution** rename the service name in *`docker-compose.yml`* or delete the running container and rebuild it again (this solution related to Unix/Linux/macOS systems):

1. get all running containers `sudo docker ps -a`
2. get the specific **container id**
3. stop and remove the duplicated container /  force remove it

```
sudo docker stop <container_id>
sudo docker rm <container_id>
```

**or**

```
sudo docker rm --force <container_id>
```

Answer (score 11):

You can remove it with command `sudo docker rm YOUR_CONTAINER_ID`, then run a new container with `sudo docker run ...`;
or restart an existing container with `sudo docker start YOUR_CONTAINER_ID`

Answer (score 8):

I have solved the issue by doing following steps and I hope it helps.

1. Type `docker ps -a` to list all the containers in your system.
2. Check the NAMES part where you have initialized your docker container.
3. Then type `docker rm --force name_of_container`
4. Install the docker container as you wish.

I had problem using NIFI and I have removed and reinstalled using docker. Good luck.

Answer (score 6):

TL:DR;

List all containers: 
`docker ps -a` 
Remove the concerned container by id: 
`docker container rm <container_id>`

Answer (score 6):

The OP's problem is the error.  Deleting state isn't the only solution - or even a good one.  The problem is `docker run` isn't re-entrant, and `docker start` is impotent w/o `run`.  So we have to combine them.

For example to run Postgres w/o destroying previous state, try this:

```
docker start postgres || docker run -d -p 5432:5432 --name postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password postgres:13-alpine
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm just learning docker and this got me as well. I stopped the container with that name already and therefore I thought I could run a new container with that name.

Not the case. Just because the container is stopped, doesn't mean it can't be started again, and it keeps all the same parameters that it was created with (including the name).

when I ran `docker ps -a` that's when I saw all the dummy test containers I created while I was playing around.

No problem, since I don't want those any more I just did `docker rm containername` at which point my new container was allowed to run with the old name.

Ah, and now that I finish writing this answer, I see Slawosz's comment on Walt Howard's answer above suggesting the use of `docker ps -a`

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so I didn't understand either, then I left my pc, went to do other things, and upon my return, it clicked :D

1. You download a docker image file. `docker pull *image-name*` will just pull the image from docker hub without running it.
2. Now, you use docker run, and give it a name (e.g. newWebServer).

   `docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -v volume --name newWebServer image-name/version`

You perhaps only need `docker run --name *name* *image*`, but the other stuff will become useful quickly.

`-d` (detached) - means the container will exit when the root process used to run the container exits.

`-p` (port) - specify the container port and the host port. Kind of the internal and external port. The internal one being the port the container uses, and the external one is the port you use outside of it and probably the one you need to put in your web browser if that's how you access your app.

`--name` (what you want to call this instance of the container) - you could have several instances of the same container all with different names, which is useful when you're trying to test something.

`image-name/version` is the actual image you want to create the container from. You can see a list of all the images on your system with `docker images -a`. You may have more than one version, so make sure you choose the correct one/tag.

`-v` (volume) - perhaps not needed initially, but soon you'll want to persist data after your container exits.

OK. So now, docker run just created a container from your image. If it isn't running, you can now start it with it's name:

```
docker start newWebServer
```

You can check all your containers (they may or may not be running) with

```
docker ps -a
```

You can stop and start them (or pause them) with their name or the container id (or just the first few characters of it) from the CONTAINER ID column e.g:

```
docker stop newWebServer

docker start c3028a89462c
```

And list all your images, with

```
docker images -a
```

In a nutshell, download an image; docker run creates a container from it; start it with docker start (name or container id); stop it with docker stop (name or container id).

Comment: docker run not just creates the container. It creates + starts the container.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue because I had two or more containers with the same `container_name` in the docker-compose.yml file.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution: Goto your docker folder in the system and delete .raw file or docker archive with large size.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was that I used an image alias more than once in the dockerfile.

[image]

Comment: This error may happen when using the same alias for multiple images

Answer (score 0):

When getting

> Error: error creating container storage: the container name "{NAME}"
> is already in use by "{ID}". You have to remove that container to be
> able to reuse that name`

While docker/podman `ps` doesn't list that container, the container might still be registered in the containers.lock file:
`/var/lib/containers/storage/overlay-containers/containers.lock`

Clearing the content of that file has resolved it for me, and I could run the same container name once more.

Answer (score -3):

This happened to me on the docker tutorial!  The port I tried to use was taken, but docker still created..  an image?  A process to run docker?  I'll find out soon.  Anyways, to choose a different port, I had to remove the older image, and then docker run again.

Sometimes a tutorial can be too terse.  What you want is concise, not terse, or even succinct.