# How to remove docker container using port number

Tags: shell, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

- I have Node services which are running in Docker container

  - I am using shell script to run these services
  - I want to run three different instances of the same service on 3 different port. say `9011 9022 9033`
  - I also want it to configure it in such a way that after every new deployment it should stop the previous service and remove it
  - I am using `docker rm test-service` to remove it but it will remove other instances too.
  - by this approach only once instance can be running.

**Is there any way to remove Docker service running on the specific port**.

here is my shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
ORGANISATION="$1"
SERVICE_NAME="$2"
VERSION="$3"
ENVIRONMENT="$4"
INTERNAL_PORT_NUMBER="$5"
EXTERNAL_PORT_NUMBER="$6"
NETWORK="$7"
docker build -t ${ORGANISATION}/${SERVICE_NAME}:${VERSION} --build-arg PORT=${INTERNAL_PORT_NUMBER} --build-arg ENVIRONMENT=${ENVIRONMENT} --no-cache .
docker stop ${SERVICE_NAME}
docker rm ${SERVICE_NAME}

sudo npm install
sudo npm install -g express
docker run -p ${EXTERNAL_PORT_NUMBER}:${INTERNAL_PORT_NUMBER} --network ${NETWORK} --name ${SERVICE_NAME} --restart always -itd ${ORGANISATION}/${SERVICE_NAME}:${VERSION}
```

Comment: Can you explain more about your use case? This sounds pretty confusing / unnecessary atm. Also the script is running containers, not services? Can you paste your exact commands?

Comment: `docker stop ${SERVICE_NAME}
docker rm ${SERVICE_NAME}` these are the commands. but it will also remove the other instance of a service as a reason I want to know is there any another way of removing the container on the basis of port

Comment: But you're not running services. Services are something very specific in Docker. What you're running is containers, and you can't run more than 1 container with the same name, so you can't actually be doing what you say you're doing anyway. Please paste the entire set of commands you're running, with `docker ps` output after each one.

Comment: I am running the shell only.From the shell file it will run the container.Please see the commands in shell file which I posted above.

Comment: As you mention I can not run more than one container with the same name. Can I run the docker service with the same name on 3 different port. if yes what modifications do i need to make in above shell fle

Comment: You simply can't have two containers using the same name. It does not matter which ports they use. Give them different names.

Comment: @Henry : Correct, So what can I do. I want to perform LoadBalance for service. So is there replica or something that I can do. I dont want to change the name of the service as I am calling this service using service name

Comment: @AnandDeshmukh You should read about docker services in swarm mode: https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/how-swarm-mode-works/services/

Answer (score 0):

> I can not run more than one container with the same name. Can I run the docker service with the same name on 3 different port. if yes what modifications do i need to make in above shell file?

That would be three [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/edge/engine/reference/run/), each using the same internal port, but mapped to a different host port, with three different names

```
docker run -p ${EXTERNAL_PORT_NUMBER1}:${INTERNAL_PORT_NUMBER} --name ${SERVICE_NAME1}
docker run -p ${EXTERNAL_PORT_NUMBER2}:${INTERNAL_PORT_NUMBER} --name ${SERVICE_NAME2} 
docker run -p ${EXTERNAL_PORT_NUMBER3}:${INTERNAL_PORT_NUMBER}  --name ${SERVICE_NAME3}
```

> I want to perform LoadBalance for service

See [docker swarm *mode*](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/key-concepts/)

> The swarm manager uses **ingress load balancing** to expose the services you want to make available externally to the swarm.
>   The swarm manager can automatically assign the service a `PublishedPort` or you can configure a `PublishedPort` for the service. You can specify any unused port. If you do not specify a port, the swarm manager assigns the service a port in the `30000-32767` range.

Example:

> the following command publishes port 80 in the nginx container to port 8080 for any node in the swarm

```
$ docker service create \
  --name my-web \
  --publish 8080:80 \
  --replicas 2 \
  nginx
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but its not possible to run the container by same name

Comment: @AnandDeshmukh no: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31698016/6309. Each container has its own id and own name.

Comment: Yes, Every docker container has its own ID but the name should be different When I try to implement I get an error saying container already exists with the same name. I don't want to change the name As I am calling this service using name